# html elements unexpectedly invisible on first page load in chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my new online portfolio at http://asbjorn.org/ny/, and I've come across the weirdest issue!

Every time you open the page for the first time, the next and previous buttons for the slideshow don't appear. If I open the inspector, they pop up immediately, and they also appear when reloading the page.

They're pretty standard html elements, not added dynamically, so I have NO clue as to why this happens! Of course I can't have the site visitors reload the page just to see them. :/

I really hope someone can help me! :)

update: seems like it's a chrome only issue. For me it happens consistently in chrome on both Win7 and OSX. A few of my friends also has the same issue (probably in chrome on osx)

Comment: If by arrows you mean the orange semi-circles next to the images, then they appear first time for me both in Chrome and FF. You've got a rather neat effect going on there I must say - nice work!

Comment: Really? For me and a couple of my friends they're all invisible on first load. Might be because we're on macs or something? Thanks btw! :)

Comment: Possibly but I doubt it. I'm running Windows 8. Which browsers/OSes have you tried your site with?

Comment: When you open the inspector, does the vertical scroll-bar appear on the page? If so, it might be triggering a reflow of the page content, resulting in a repaint (thereby getting them to show up).

Comment: Works fine for me in FF on Win7.

Comment: @JamWaffles, Tried with all regular browsers on Win7, and chrome on OSX.

Comment: @JonahBishop, yeah, a scrollbar appears when I open the inspector. Is there a way to force this repaint?

Comment: I can reproduce in Chrome 21 on windows 7...

Comment: Working fine - Chrome W7

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to explicitly ask for a repaint. I see the issue in Chrome 22 on Windows 7, and opening the inspector interestingly enough did _not_ get them to show up for me (even though the scroll bar appeared). Toggling one of the element's styles did make them appear though. This feels to me like some sort of browser-based bug...

Comment: @JonahBishop That's so weird :S Still, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'll take a stab at an answer. When I see the problem in Chrome 22, and I bring up the inspector, I note that the `#previousLink` and `#nextLink` divs have a `width` of 0 in the broken state. Try setting an explicit width for these in your CSS, or make the nested image use `display: block`.

```
#previousLink { width: 31px; }
#nextLink { width: 37px; }
```

or

```
#previousLink img,
#nextLink img { display: block; }
```

I think the combination of these inline items and your `overflow: hidden` rule are biting you. I *think*. This is a tricky bug!

Comment: I think removing overflow: hidden fixed it :)
Thanks a lot man! :)
At least it's working in chrome on osx now ^^

Comment: If you want to keep `overflow:hidden` (which seems like a legitimate thing to want to do), try setting either the `width` or `min-width` of those elements. I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Yeah, I actually don't need the overflow hidden at all. That must've been what caused the semicircles to clip on mobile aswell, so you pretty much saved the day mister

Comment: Yippee! Glad to have helped out.